# How to save output JSON file from a Docker container with Python script

Tags: python, json, pandas, docker

I am really new to docker and I have a python script that takes several input csv files and gives a json as output.

My DockerFile is

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /usr/workdir

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY annotation_tool.py .

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-u" , "./annotation_tool.py"]
```

My container works with this command:

```
sudo docker run --rm -v /home/huk/Desktop/idea/varskor_annotation/docker_try:'/input/' varskor_annotation /input/out_total_filtered_2.vcf /input/HumanNet_XI_Network_Stats.csv /input/exac_gnomad_freq.csv /input/gnomad.v2.1.1.lof_metrics.by_transcript.txt
```

I can give the inputs but I cannot find my output JSON anywhere. Is there a way to directly write the output file to the folder I work on (the -v parameter) ?

Basically my Python code is:

```
file1 = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1]) 
file2 = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[2])
file3 = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[3])
file4 = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[4] , sep = '\t')

##### AFTER THE MODIFICATIONS I CREATE AN OUTPUT FILE IN A PANDAS DATAFRAME FORMAT

output_file.to_json('output.json' , orient = 'records')
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing to a file `output.json` with no particular path, it will write to the directory that's the `WORKDIR`.  The file is in the container filesystem, which is immediately deleted by the `docker run --rm` option as soon as the script completes.  You can't mount something over that directory because that's also where your code is located.

If you take the location of the output file as an additional parameter

```py
output_file.to_json(sys.argv[5], orient='records')
```

then you can pass a file name like `/input/output.json` in the bind-mounted directory in the container startup.

---

As you're seeing, one of the design goals of Docker is that it's intentionally difficult to read and write host files.  The setup you show doesn't seem to especially need Docker: you don't have any complicated OS-level dependencies and you're not interacting with any other programs that are running in containers.

You might find it easier to run this in a Python virtual environment, without involving Docker.  Linux and MacOS systems come with Python preinstalled so you may not need to do any host-level setup at all.

```bash
python3 -m venv ./venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt

./annotation_tool.py \
  out_total_filtered_2.vcf \
  HumanNet_XI_Network_Stats.csv \
  exac_gnomad_freq.csv \
  gnomad.v2.1.1.lof_metrics.by_transcript.txt
```